# Not able to compile a .msg using pcl_msgs type variables

Tags: pcl, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I am working on Groovy and have all the libraries installed.

I have created a custom .msg file with following entries :

Header header

pcl_msgs/PolygonMesh mesh

sensor_msgs/PointCloud2 normals

I have included pcl_msgs in my package.xml and CMakelists.txt also.

But unfortunately on compilation I get following errors

```
-- checking for module 'openni-dev'
--   package 'openni-dev' not found
-- Could NOT find openni (missing:  OPENNI_INCLUDE_DIRS) 
** WARNING ** io features related to openni will be disabled
-- checking for module 'openni-dev'
--   package 'openni-dev' not found
-- Could NOT find openni (missing:  OPENNI_INCLUDE_DIRS) 
** WARNING ** visualization features related to openni will be disabled
-- looking for PCL_COMMON
-- looking for PCL_KDTREE
-- looking for PCL_OCTREE
-- looking for PCL_SEARCH
-- looking for PCL_SAMPLE_CONSENSUS
-- looking for PCL_IO
-- looking for PCL_GEOMETRY
-- looking for PCL_FEATURES
-- looking for PCL_FILTERS
-- looking for PCL_KEYPOINTS
-- looking for PCL_SURFACE
-- looking for PCL_REGISTRATION
-- looking for PCL_SEGMENTATION
-- looking for PCL_VISUALIZATION
-- looking for PCL_TRACKING
CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/genmsg/cmake/genmsg-extras.cmake:252 (message):
  Could not find 'share/pcl_msgs/cmake/pcl_msgs-msg-paths.cmake' (searched in
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  modsrc/CMakeLists.txt:31 (generate_messages)
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

### CMakelist:

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)

project(mod_msgs)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
nav_msgs
roscpp
rospy
sensor_msgs
std_msgs
message_generation
pcl
pcl_ros
pcl_msgs
)

add_message_files(
FILES
TriangleMesh.msg
)

generate_messages(
DEPENDENCIES

nav_msgs

sensor_msgs

std_msgs

pcl

pcl_ros

pcl_msgs
)

catkin_package(

CATKIN_DEPENDS nav_msgs roscpp rospy sensor_msgs std_msgs message_runtime pcl_msgs pcl pcl_ros
)

include_directories(

${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS}

${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})

add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

I have looked through  pcl forums but not able to resolve this problem. Any kind of guidance would be much appreciated.
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/137031/not-able-to-compile-a-.msg-using-pcl_msgs-type-variables/) by [rosAS](https://answers.ros.org/users/9296/rosas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2014-03-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like the pcl_msgs that are released into Groovy are in the pcl namespace; try declaring your message dependency on pcl instead of pcl_msgs.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks a lot ahendrix, exactly this was the issue. I checked in the documentaion of pcl 1.6, they are using the namespace pcl, for e.g. pcl::PolygonMesh , so using the namespace "pcl" worked.
Here is the link : http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.6.0/search.php?query=polygonmesh

---

Originally posted by [rosAS](https://answers.ros.org/users/9296/rosas/) with karma: 21 on 2014-03-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1